# In Angular9's mat-table, how do I enforce that DIVs within a mat-cell start new lines?

Tags: html, css, angular9, mat-table

I'm using Angular 9.  I have defined a very simple mat-table element ...

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="article">
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let article_stat">
      <div>Hello</div>
      <div>Good-bye</div>
    </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

These are the only styles I have in the component ...

```
.mat-row {
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

.mat-cell {
  padding-top: .5em;
  padding-bottom: .5em;
}
```

However, when my table renders, the two different DIVs are aligning on the same horizontal plane.

[image]

I thought DIVs were supposed to wrap to different lines, especially since I haven't applied any additional styles, but I'm not sure what else I need to do to restore the original DIV behavior.

**Edit:** Per the answer, I tried this

```
<mat-cell *matCellDef="let article_stat">
<div class="smallHeading">
{{ article_stat.article.path }}
</div>
<div class='mainRow'>
...
</div>
</mat-cell>
```

with css

```
.smallHeading, .mainRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

but still the DIVs appear on the same horizontal line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `mat-table` and `mat-cell` directives incorrectly.

You need to place the directives as attributes on vanilla `table` and `td` elements.

```
<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="article">
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let article_stat">
      <div>Hello</div>
      <div>Good-bye</div>
    </td>
    </ng-container>
</table>
```

Now, you cell content will be placed on separate lines :)

See for more info: https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Answer (score 0):

Did u try it as below?

HTML

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="article">
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let article_stat">
      <div class="multi-line">
        <div>Hello</div>
        <div>Good-bye</div>
      </div>
    </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
</mat-table>
```

CSS

```
.multi-line {
   display: block; width: 100%;
}
```

Hope it will help. If it is not your requirement then clarify a bit more.

Comment: This doesn't work because you are using the `mat-*` directives incorrectly. You should consider testing your solution before posting.

Comment: To be fair, even the examples on the official website use the mat-* directives "incorrectly". I will say between the two, using them as you say seems to have less issues personally.
https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-flex-basic